# Monitor response time longer than the refresh period

Tags: display, refresh-rate

How can a monitor have a response time longer than the refresh period?

eg: [LG monitor 34UC79G-B](http://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-34UC79G-B-ultrawide-monitor)

Refresh rate: 144 Hz 
Response time: 15 ms

- Refresh rate period: 1000*1/144 = 6.94 ms.
- Response time max frequency: (1/ (15/2))*1000 = 133.33 Hz !

Response time should be divided by two since it refers to change and go back to same state.

So, the monitor needs to have a response time < 6.94 ms! How can it have a response time max frequency of 66.67 Hz and a refresh rate of 144 Hz? This does not make any sense!

Answer (score 1):

#### How can it have a response time max frequency of 66.67 Hz and a refresh rate of 144 Hz?

> This does not make any sense!

That's because they are measuring different things:

> "**Response time is how quickly the display can have a LCD pixel to change from fully active (white) to fully inactive (black), then back to fully active again**. A lower response time typically means less ghosting of the image and better picture quality."
>
> This differs from **refresh rate, which is how many times per second the panel can redraw the image.** With refresh rate you want a higher number, response time you want to go lower. It's measured in milliseconds, so a 5ms response time means that a monitor can go from white to black to white in 1/200th of a second.

Source [What you need to know about monitor response times | Windows Central](https://www.windowscentral.com/what-does-response-time-mean-your-pc-monitor)

---

#### Further Reading

- [What you need to know about monitor refresh rates | Windows Central](https://www.windowscentral.com/what-does-refresh-rate-mean-your-pc-monitor)
- [A Gamer's Guide to Refresh Rates and Response Times](https://www.tomsguide.com/us/refresh-rates-vs-response-times,news-24345.html)
- [Factors Affecting PC Monitor Responsiveness | PC Monitors](https://pcmonitors.info/articles/factors-affecting-pc-monitor-responsiveness/)

Comment: I miss that I need to divide the response time by 2. "That's because they are measuring different things" in terms, since if the response period can NOT be larger then the display period. But still 7.5 ms is not fast enough. Takes more time to change the pixel than the refresh period.

Comment: This is not a valid answer to the question asked. Even I am wondering, how can any monitor have response time greater than refresh rate?